# Using MAPI to create a PST file with WinRM

Tags: powershell, outlook, mapi, winrm, dcom

I have the following PowerShell code which creates a PST file

```
enter code Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.AddStore("C:\tmp\file.pst")
```

Running this code locally works excellent, but I have to run this code remotely. The script is sitting on the Windows machine and I'm starting it from Linux using WinRM (python) in that setup, it hangs on AddStore(). I assume this is related to user/security context but I can't find the resolution or info if it is possible to run it with some configuration changes.

EDIT: Ok, it is not hanging it just taking a long time before it will fail with the following error:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed 
due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 
(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
At C:\\tmp\\pst.ps1:3 char:12
+ $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\\tmp\\pst.ps1:4 char:1
+ $namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\\tmp\\pst.ps1:6 char:1
+ $namespace.AddStore("C:\\tmp\\file.pst")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

'

Answer (score 1):

`CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE` means Outlook.exe and your code are running in different security contexts, and hence the COM system refuses to marshal calls between the two processes.

Firstly, Outlook cannot be used from anything that runs outside of an interactive user context (such as service or a scheduled task). Secondly, does it work if Outlook is not yet running on the target machine?

That being said, Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) code runs in-proc might be able to do the job. If C++ or Delphi are not an option, you can try [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) - [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonPstStore` is probably what you need - it creates and deletes a temporary profile that loads the specified PST file.